# force utilisation of a specific library at execution

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I compile an executable with option to use specific library (not system library). Compilation is ok.

But when I execute this binary, despite having specified `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to these specific Library, I have an error on `libc`, about wrong version of `glib` found :

```
./bin: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /home/user/ptxdist/platform-i586/sysroot-target/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0)
```

And it's normal as executable use system `libc` instead of specific `libc`... A `ldd` on executable show the problem :

```
[user ~/Desktop/gesram_x86 ] ldd -v bin 
./bin: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /home/user/ptxdist/platform-i586/sysroot-target/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0)
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7704000)
    libgesram.so.0 => /home/user/Desktop/gesram_x86/gesram/lib_gesram/.libs/libgesram.so.0 (0xb76f9000)
    libsofutils.so.0 => /home/user/ptxdist/platform-i586/sysroot-target/applications/base/lib/libsofutils.so.0 (0xb76f1000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb7531000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /home/user/ptxdist/platform-i586/sysroot-target/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xb7403000)
    libgio-2.0.so.0 => /home/user/ptxdist/platform-i586/sysroot-target/usr/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0xb721b000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /home/user/ptxdist/platform-i586/sysroot-target/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0xb71bc000)
    libffi.so.6 => /home/user/ptxdist/platform-i586/sysroot-target/usr/lib/libffi.so.6 (0xb71b3000)
    libpcre.so.1 => /home/user/ptxdist/platform-i586/sysroot-target/usr/lib/libpcre.so.1 (0xb713b000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /home/user/ptxdist/platform-i586/sysroot-target/usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0xb7137000)
    libz.so.1 => /home/user/ptxdist/platform-i586/sysroot-target/usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0xb711c000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xb7112000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xb70f6000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7705000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xb70f1000)

    Version information:
    ./bin:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /home/user/Desktop/gesram_x86/gesram/lib_gesram/.libs/libgesram.so.0:
        libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1.3) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /home/user/ptxdist/platform-i586/sysroot-target/applications/base/lib/libsofutils.so.0:
        librt.so.1 (GLIBC_2.2) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1
        libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.8) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1.3) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:
        ld-linux.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/ld-linux.so.2
        ld-linux.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/ld-linux.so.2
        ld-linux.so.2 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/ld-linux.so.2
    /home/user/ptxdist/platform-i586/sysroot-target/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0:
        libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.12) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
        libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.2) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
        libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
        libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.9) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.11) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.8) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.7) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1.3) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.15) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => not found
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1.2) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /home/user/ptxdist/platform-i586/sysroot-target/usr/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0:
        libz.so.1 (ZLIB_1.2.2) => /home/user/ptxdist/platform-i586/sysroot-target/usr/lib/libz.so.1
        libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.2) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
        libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.9) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1.2) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.12) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1.3) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.3) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.5) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /home/user/ptxdist/platform-i586/sysroot-target/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1.3) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /home/user/ptxdist/platform-i586/sysroot-target/usr/lib/libffi.so.6:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1.3) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.7) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /home/user/ptxdist/platform-i586/sysroot-target/usr/lib/libpcre.so.1:
        libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1.3) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /home/user/ptxdist/platform-i586/sysroot-target/usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so.0:
        libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
        libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.2) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
        libdl.so.2 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
        libdl.so.2 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1.3) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /home/user/ptxdist/platform-i586/sysroot-target/usr/lib/libz.so.1:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1.3) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1:
        libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
        libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
        libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
        libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.2) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.2) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1.3) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0:
        ld-linux.so.2 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/ld-linux.so.2
        ld-linux.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/ld-linux.so.2
        ld-linux.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/ld-linux.so.2
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.2) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1.3) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2:
        ld-linux.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/ld-linux.so.2
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1.3) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

All link to `/lib/` or `/usr/lib/` library are wrong...

Here is my compilation command :

```
/opt/OSELAS.Toolchain-2016.06.0/toolchain-i586/bin/i586-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -o bin fichier.c -I/home/user/include -I/home/usr/ptxdist/platform-i586/sysroot-target/usr/include/glib-2.0/ -Wl,-rpath,gesram/lib_gesram/.libs/ -Lgesram/lib_gesram/.libs/ -lgesram -Wl,-rpath,/home/user/ptxdist/platform-i586/sysroot-target/applications/base/lib/ -L/home/user/ptxdist/platform-i586/sysroot-target/applications/base/lib/ -lsofutils -Wl,-rpath,/opt/OSELAS.Toolchain-2016.06.0/toolchain-i586/sysroot-i586-unknown-linux-gnu/usr/lib/ -L/opt/OSELAS.Toolchain-2016.06.0/toolchain-i586/sysroot-i586-unknown-linux-gnu/usr/lib/ -lc -Wl,-rpath,/home/user/ptxdist/platform-i586/sysroot-target/usr/lib/ -L/home/user/ptxdist/platform-i586/sysroot-target/usr/lib/ -lglib-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lffi -lpcre -lgmodule-2.0 -lz
```

Is it a way to force use of a specific library at execution time ?

There is a part of output of LD_DEBUG=all ./bin (thanks Ctx) :

```
 24006: file=libc.so.6 [0];  needed by ./bin [0]
 24006: find library=libc.so.6 [0]; searching
 24006:  search path=/home/ggau/Desktop/gesram_x86/gesram/lib_gesram/.libs:/home/ggau/integration/ptxdist/platform-i586/sysroot-target/applications/base/lib:/opt/OSELAS.Toolchain-2016.06.0/toolchain-i586/sysroot-i586-unknown-linux-g
    [...]
 24006:   trying file=/opt/OSELAS.Toolchain-2016.06.0/toolchain-i586/sysroot-i586-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/sse2/libc.so.6
 24006:   trying file=/opt/OSELAS.Toolchain-2016.06.0/toolchain-i586/sysroot-i586-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/cmov/libc.so.6
 24006:   trying file=/opt/OSELAS.Toolchain-2016.06.0/toolchain-i586/sysroot-i586-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libc.so.6
 24006:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
 24006:   trying file=/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
 24006: 
 24006: file=libc.so.6 [0];  generating link map
 24006:   dynamic: 0xb77a4d7c  base: 0xb75fd000   size: 0x001abadc
 24006:     entry: 0xb7616690  phdr: 0xb75fd034  phnum:         10
```

I don't understand why executable don't use this file `/opt/OSELAS.Toolchain-2016.06.0/toolchain-i586/sysroot-i586-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libc.so.6` because it is the good file...

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 May 31 17:45 /opt/OSELAS.Toolchain-2016.06.0/toolchain-i586/sysroot-i586-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.23.so*
```

It try this file just before trying `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`...

Comment: Starting your binary with `LD_DEBUG=all ./bin` will provide more information on this issue

Comment: Thanks, this flag is very usefull. I edit my question, I don't understand the choice executable made to choose libc to use ... Have you some idea to check why it don't use good one ?

Comment: With that many custom libraries being linked in, I'd be sorely temped to statically link everything, especially if the binary didn't have to run on systems running different OS revisions.

Comment: For the question "I don't understand the choice executable made to choose libc to use", LD_DEBUG output have not to be read sequentially. Each "trying file" line is just an information about where linker can search, but not the order in which it will test them. Linker start to search within cache. It found path to system libc within it, and stop it search. It's why it's system libc that is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting it short, you can`t force the app to use your own GLIBC without providing your own dynamic linker native to this very GLIBC.

64-bit:

```
-Wl,--rpath=<path to glibc 64-bit libs>
-Wl,--dynamic-linker=<path to glibc 64-bit libs>/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

32-bit:

```
-Wl,--rpath=<path to glibc 32-bit libs>
-Wl,--dynamic-linker=<path to glibc 32-bit libs>/ld-linux.so.2
```

Comment: Thanks, this option help me move forward. Now I'am blocked by version of kernel that is too old for the libc version of the toolchain... This is no more a technical problem, it will be more convenient to update my linux version... Many thanks for help!